# Eloquent select through relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Company, User and Partner models. User belongsTo Company, Company hasMany User, User hasMany Partner.
I want to get a collection with all partners from all the users from some company, something like

```
Company::with('users.partners')->where([['companies.id', '=', 1]])->get();
```

This eager load gives me

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1422 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Company {#1421 ▼
      #guarded: []
      +timestamps: false
      #connection: "sqlite"
      #table: "companies"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:3 [▶]
      #original: array:3 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "users" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1426 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => App\User {#1429 ▼
              +timestamps: false
              #fillable: array:5 [▶]
              #hidden: array:2 [▶]
              #casts: array:1 [▶]
              #connection: "sqlite"
              #table: "users"
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:9 [▶]
              #original: array:9 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #classCastCache: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: array:1 [▼
                "partners" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1439 ▶}
              ]
              #touches: []
              #visible: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
              #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
              #accessToken: null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
    }
  ]
}
```

And from this, how can I pluck only the partners? Is it possible?
Or if it's not possible this way, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Partner::whereHas('user.company', function($query) use ($companyId) {
   $query->where('id', $companyId);
})
```